# Memoization+Recursion and DP array filling order

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, dynamic-programming, memoization

I have solved the below problem with recursion and memoization.

**Given a string s. In one step you can insert any character at any index of the string.

Return the minimum number of steps to make s palindrome.**

Here is my code

```
class Scratch {

    public static int makepalind(String s, int left, int right, int [][]dp) {
        if (left > right) return 0;
        if (left == right) {
            return 0;
        }

        if (dp[left][right] != -1) return dp[left][right];
        if (s.charAt(left) == s.charAt(right)) {
            dp[left][right] = makepalind(s, left + 1, right - 1, dp);
            return dp[left][right];
        }

        dp[left][right] = 1 + Math.min(makepalind(s, left + 1, right, dp), makepalind(s, left, right - 1, dp));
        return dp[left][right];
    }
        public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "leetcode" ;
        //String s = "appa" ;
        //String s = "leetcode";
        int [][]dp = new int[s.length()][s.length()];
        for(var arr:dp) {
            Arrays.fill(arr,-1);
        }
        makepalind(s,0,s.length()-1,dp);
        // Fill array with 0 and create new array
        for(int i = 0; i<s.length(); i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j<s.length(); j++) {
                if(dp[i][j]==-1) {
                    dp[i][j] = 0;
                }
            }
        }
        for(int i = 0; i<s.length(); i++)  {
            for(int j = 0; j<s.length(); j++) {
                System.out.format("%2d",dp[i][j]);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

This code works. But I have some questions on this

Example 1:

Input string "leetcode"
If I print the `dp` array it comes out as below

```
 0 1 1 2 3 4 5 5
 0 0 0 1 2 3 4 4
 0 0 0 1 2 3 4 0
 0 0 0 0 1 2 3 0
 0 0 0 0 0 1 2 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

As can be seen the answer is correct because at zeroth row and col 7, the number is `5`
However this array is filled due to recursion in an order which is opposite of how it will get filled if I were to use two for loops beginning from index 0 and going till input string's length.

Example 2:

It gets more obvious if I use `madam` which is a palindrome string.

```
 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0
```

If however, I were to use the nested for loops that start from 0, the DP array for `madam` string won't show up like this. I know that this is due to how recursion is unfolding.
I am however, unable to change the recursion and trying to figure out how do I do it so that recursion folds in the opposite way.

Comment: To me the dp matrix looks as I would expect it and I am not clear on how you would have produced a different matrix with an iterative algorithm. Could you add the iterative code that you would have used to produce something different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> this array is filled due to recursion in an order which is opposite of how it will get filled if I were to use two for loops beginning from index 0 and going till input string's length.

The order of the array is as expected. It gives information for all analysed substrings, by using the start index of that substring as Y-coordinate (row index) and the end index (inclusive) of that substring as X-coordinate (column index). With that meaning of row and column index there is no other way to represent the matrix. So in the case of "leetcode" we could represent that `dp` matrix -- with the labels for row and column indices -- as follows:

```
  | 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
--+----------------
0 | 0 1 1 2 3 4 5 5
1 | 0 0 0 1 2 3 4 4
2 | 0 0 0 1 2 3 4 0
3 | 0 0 0 0 1 2 3 0
4 | 0 0 0 0 0 1 2 0
5 | 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0
6 | 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
7 | 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

So if for instance we want to know how many insertions are needed to make the substring at indices 2 to 4 a palindrome (where we have the string "etc"), we would look in row 2 and column 4, where we find the value 2. The matrix clearly has to be structured in this order for this lookup to work that way. This is not related to the choice to use recursion, but rather how the matrix is supposed to work for storing and looking up data.

#### Different structure

If you would want to have the solution value to appear at the bottom, you'll have to come up with a different encoding strategy. Since we want the solution for the whole string, which starts at index 0 and ends at index 7, you might want to reverse row/column indices in your matrix, so that the matrix appears as:

```
  | 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
--+----------------
0 | 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
1 | 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
2 | 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
3 | 2 1 1 0 0 0 0 0
4 | 3 2 2 1 0 0 0 0
5 | 4 3 3 2 1 0 0 0
6 | 5 4 4 3 2 1 0 0
7 | 5 5 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

To achieve this, just change row/column index when accessing `dp`:

```java
public static int makepalind(String s, int left, int right, int [][]dp) {
    if (left > right) return 0;
    if (left == right) {
        return 0;
    }

    if (dp[right][left] != -1) return dp[right][left];
    if (s.charAt(left) == s.charAt(right)) {
        dp[right][left] = makepalind(s, left + 1, right - 1, dp);
        return dp[right][left];
    }

    dp[right][left] = 1 + Math.min(makepalind(s, left + 1, right, dp), makepalind(s, left, right - 1, dp));
    return dp[right][left];
}
```

There are several other alternative "encodings" you can use for the matrix. For instance, you could use for the row index the right index (as above), but for the column index the *difference* between the left and right index (so `right - left`). Then the solution will come up in the bottom-right corner of the matrix.

> if I use madam which is a palindrome string: (all zeroes)

The zeroes that you see in the matrix that is produced for input "madam" are mostly put there by the main program *after* the function has already returned. Only tow of those zeroes are really produced by the recursive algorithm: the one for substring "ada" and the one for "madam". The thing is that as soon as the algorithm finds the palindrome, it returns out of recursion without investigating any other possibilities. It is then the main program that replaces all the other unvisited cells in the matrix.

If you want the algorithm to also look at other substrings (which makes it less optimal), then *first* perform the two recursive calls you now do at the very end:

```java
// Do this first
dp[right][left] = 1 + Math.min(makepalind(s, left + 1, right, dp), makepalind(s, left, right - 1, dp));
// ...and only then:
if (s.charAt(left) == s.charAt(right)) {
    dp[right][left] = makepalind(s, left + 1, right - 1, dp);
}
return dp[right][left];
```

Comment: Thanks @trincot, I can ask this as a separate question but I must clarify my question. Here is what I was trying to cite which I failed to. Trying to clairfy. If you look at the array my code generates for leetcode, if you go to row for where `c` starts and col where `c` starts u can get ans for `code`. Basically, sub matrix gives u answers for substrings correctly. However if the original string like `madam` the entire array is zero and I do not get right ans for `mad` from the matrix for `madam`. If I were to generate the matrix using my code for `mad` I will get the ans as 2. Is Q clear?

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood the paragraph below example 1 where you speak of the unexpected order. I tried to explain why it is like that. Concerning the all-zero output you get for "madam", see the addition to my answer. I'm not sure what else you expect in an answer?

Comment: thanks a bunch for all the help you provide. I was having a blindspot to the fact that the very point of memoization is to cash what it can and also not call any recursive path if it need not. Keep being so nice and articulate. You are awesome